# How can we take into account post types when constructing permalinks?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, apache

When I'm working with Wordpress's permalink system, I can create plenty of options  for creating permalinks, like so:

`/blog/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`

But if I add introduce a new kind of content type, say portfolio pieces, so I can have a url like:

`/portfolio/postname/`

The permalink options I do have (and have been using for the last 3-4 year's worth of posts), means that end up with ugly urls like:

/blog/portfolio/usual_path

I want all the existing links to work for posts that have already been at:

`blog/YYYY/MM/post-name`

But I also want to make custom posts available at:

`portfolio/post-name`

#### How I'd normally do it

The approach I've normally do would be:

- remove the hard coded blog slug, from the permalinks to that the new permalink structure was `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`
- Add a rule in apache to 301 all requests for domain.com/blog/YYYY/MM/DD/old-post to domain.com/YYYY/MM/old-post, for SEO and suchlike.

As far as I know, this would mean that any existing links to

`http://domain.com/blog/YYYY/MM/DD/old-post` would still work, although browsers would end up at:

`http://domain.com/YYYY/MM/DD/old-post`

I'd still have the decent urls for custom post types too, at

`http://domain.com/portfolio/post-name`

#### Is this how you'd do it?

I feel fairly comfortable about this approach - I could improve the naming structure for SEO while maintaining performance, by removing the days or even years and have something like this:

`/%year%/%postname%/`

I'm not sure how I'd allow for custom permalink structure here, but is there anything else I should bear in mind here when fixing links like this?

Answer (score 1):

When you register your taxonomy you can create the rewrite rule for the slug

register_taxonomy('investment_country',array('investment'), array(                                         'hierarchical' => true,                                         'labels' => $labels,                                            'show_ui' => true,                                          'query_var' => true,                                            **'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'country' ),**                                              ));

so whenever I'm showing something that I have included in the country taxonomy I get 
http://www.domain.com/country/unitedkingdom for example

don't forget you'll need to resave your permalinks

Answer (score 0):

hope you are created custom pot type called portfolio, as of my understanding just go to custom permalink structure should be /%postname%/

And create custom category or archive template to get hold on porfolio category template

have a look at template hierarchy 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

in your case your template name should be category-porfolio.php
for single.php it should be single-portfolio.php

these templates are exclusive for your portfolio post type

Comment: Hi S kumar, that's not the issue 

The question is more about routing - because there's a hardcoded 'blog' in the permalinks slug, all custom-post type urls end up with 'blog' prepended. I'm trying to make the content available at a specific url. Thanks anyway though!